# Create a new /dev/sd{b,c,d} on WSL for Ceph

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubernetes, ceph

I'm trying to run Ceph on (micro)K8s which running on my Ubuntu WSL distory.

OSD pods are not being created because there is no supported device is available (see logs below).

Ceph is configured to [UseAllDevices](https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.5/ceph-common-issues.html#osd-pods-are-not-created-on-my-devices) which you can see it searching for one in the log above.

Ceph ideally wants an unformatted partition which I created on my windows host but I'm unsure how I mount that to `/dev/sd{c}` or do try to create a new partition within WSL itself?

I don't know how to do either or if that is even the right approach.

Thanks in advance.

```
2021-03-01 17:09:17.090302 W | inventory: skipping device "loop0". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.112037 W | inventory: skipping device "loop1". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.150605 W | inventory: skipping device "loop2". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.173562 W | inventory: skipping device "loop3". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.185464 W | inventory: skipping device "loop4". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.209067 W | inventory: skipping device "loop5". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.224485 W | inventory: skipping device "loop6". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.246726 W | inventory: skipping device "loop7". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.257490 W | inventory: skipping device "loop8". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.272513 W | inventory: skipping device "loop9". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.292126 W | inventory: skipping device "loop10". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.301785 W | inventory: skipping device "loop11". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.323591 W | inventory: skipping device "loop12". unsupported diskType loop
2021-03-01 17:09:17.327819 W | inventory: skipping device "loop13". diskType is empty
2021-03-01 17:09:20.140453 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram0": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:21.762693 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram1": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:23.759026 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram2": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:25.396302 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram3": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:26.512274 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram4": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:27.664515 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram5": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:28.854953 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram6": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:30.080786 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram7": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:31.407741 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram8": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:32.646524 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram9": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:33.856632 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram10": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:35.568848 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram11": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:36.766882 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram12": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:37.800115 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram13": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:38.895007 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram14": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:40.013397 I | cephosd: skipping device "ram15": ["Insufficient space (<5GB)"].
2021-03-01 17:09:40.013498 I | cephosd: skipping device "sda" because it contains a filesystem "ext4"
2021-03-01 17:09:40.013513 I | cephosd: skipping device "sdb" because it contains a filesystem "ext4"
2021-03-01 17:09:41.237145 W | cephosd: skipping OSD configuration as no devices matched the storage settings for this node
```

Answer (score 1):

WSL does not (yet) support mounting additional physical or virtual disks, other than the NTFS (drvfs/9P) disks already available.  That capability is coming, but it's still in [preview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) at this time.

Even then, it sounds like the filesystem will already need to be in place on the drive in order to mount it.  It doesn't *sound* like we will be able to add raw, unformatted partitions, but perhaps there will be a workaround.

Comment: Okay, great. I got the preview but since physical disk 0 is already mounted, because my partition is unformatted I can't see it? Only if it is NTFS?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - My NTFS comment was about *existing* (non-Preview) WSL.  For Preview, honestly not sure, since I'm not on the Insider ring myself.  But it does sound like from that doc page that you can (from PowerShell) get the drive *path* through `wmic diskdrive list brief`, then mount the *drive* with `wsl --mount <DiskPath> --bare`, then see the partitions with `lsblk`?

Comment: I was able to do it by creating a vhdx and mounting that! Will answer below, thank you for setting me on the right path.

Comment: Excellent - Good to hear that works.  Looking forward to this capability coming to the mainline release soon.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a couple days to sort out but, to get this working you need to:

1. Get the developer preview of Windows 10 so you have the `--mount` option for WSL
2. Create a VHDX on your Windows Host. You can do this through your Disk Manager and creating a dynamic VHDX under the actions menu.
3. Follow @NotTheDr01ds suggstion of mounting that VHDX and, voila the 1/dev/sd{x}1 will be created. In my use-case this allowed Ceph to create the OSDs using that disk.